# Excel file is not printed out completely

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, jacob

I am using JACOB to print out the Excel file. This file is created by means of Apache POI. When I save the file or send it to Outlook, everything is OK, the file contains all sheets. But when I send the file to shared printer, it starts to print, but then show the error: Error - Sent to printer. The size of a printing job is about 230 kB, so it should not be too big.

**UPDATE:** I was able to print out the file when I did not update it before printing. But now by pressing the button "Print out" I has to mark cells, which contains values outside the limits, with red color and only after that call the  printing function.

**UPDATE2**: I converted Excel file into PDF and printed it out using Apache PDFBox - still the same problem. No errors in Java, some sheets from the document are printed and then printer error occurs: Error-Sent to printer.

**UPDATE3**: I added a function, which I use to fill in the Excel sheets.

Where is a problem? Below you can find a code for printing function:

```
public class AppExcelPrinter { 
    private ActiveXComponent excel; 
    private Dispatch workbooks; 
    private Variant workbook; 
    public AppExcelPrinter() { } 
    public synchronized void print(String filename, String printer)  { 
        try { 
            ComThread.InitMTA(); 
            excel = new ActiveXComponent("Excel.Application");  //we are going to listen to events on Application   
            excel.setProperty("Visible", new Variant(false));   //the file will be invisible during printing      
            workbooks = excel.getProperty("WorkBooks").toDispatch(); 
            workbook = Dispatch.callN(workbooks, "Open", new Object[] { filename }); 
            Variant From =new Variant(1);  
            Variant To =new Variant(6);  //I have 6 sheets in my Excel file
            Variant Copies =new Variant(1);  
            Variant Preview =new Variant(false);  
            Variant ActivePrinter =new Variant(printer); 
            Variant PrintToFile = new Variant(false);
            Variant Collate = new Variant(false);
            Object[] args=new Object[]{From, To, Copies, Preview, ActivePrinter, PrintToFile, Collate};
            Dispatch.call(Dispatch.get(workbook.toDispatch(), "Worksheets").toDispatch(), "PrintOut", args); 
            try { 
                Thread.sleep(100);}// the sleep is required to let everything clear out after the quit
            catch (InterruptedException e) { 
                e.printStackTrace();}}
        finally { 
            Variant f = new Variant(false);
            Dispatch.call(workbook.toDispatch(), "Close", f);
            excel.invoke("Quit", new Variant[] {});  
            ComThread.Release(); }}    
 }
```

Function to fill in the sheets:

```
Path original = Paths.get("");
String original1=original.toAbsolutePath().toString();
String original2=original1+"\\example.xlsx";
Path path1 = Paths.get(original2);
String target = original1+"\\temp\\temp.xlsx";
Path path2 = Paths.get(target);
try {    // Copy template, which will be filled in
    Files.copy(path1, path2, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);}
catch (IOException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error while working with temporary files", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}
try {

    String VCAMvexp1=jTable16.getModel().getValueAt(2, 0).toString();
    ... //I have 6 jTables with 15 rows and 10 columns
    try {
            FileInputStream temp_file = new FileInputStream(new File(target)); 
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(temp_file);
            XSSFSheet worksheet = wb.getSheetAt(0); //separate sheet for each jTable
            XSSFSheet worksheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(1);
            XSSFSheet worksheet2 = wb.getSheetAt(2);
            XSSFSheet worksheet3 = wb.getSheetAt(3);
            XSSFSheet worksheet4 = wb.getSheetAt(4);
            XSSFSheet worksheet5 = wb.getSheetAt(5);
            CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
            style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
            style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            style.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THICK);
            style.setBottomBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
            style.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THICK);
            style.setLeftBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
            style.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THICK);
            style.setRightBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
            style.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THICK);
            style.setTopBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
            style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
            Font font = wb.createFont();
            font.setFontHeightInPoints((short)10);
            font.setFontName("Arial");
            style.setFont(font);
            Cell VCAMvexp1cell = worksheet.getRow(12).getCell(6);   
            VCAMvexp1cell.setCellValue(VCAMvexp1);
            if (Float.parseFloat(VCAMvexp1)<Float.parseFloat(VCAMvexp1_min) || Float.parseFloat(VCAMvexp1)>Float.parseFloat(VCAMvexp1_max)) {
                VCAMvexp1cell.setCellStyle(style);}
            ... //fill in the sheets and mark cells with red color
            temp_file.close(); 
            FileOutputStream output_file = new FileOutputStream(new File(target));
            wb.write(output_file);
            output_file.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}
        catch (IOException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot save the data. Table is not filled in completely", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I know of a single printer that's able to print native Excel workbooks when sent one! Some printers will be able to print a PDF or PS, rest need their own native formats. What happens if you convert to a printable format first before sending to the printer?

Comment: @Gagravarr This printer is able to print Excel workbooks. I have already printed this file using my application. But this was when I just printed it. Now I need to make some analysis (see update) in the Excel workbook before printing. I call my printing function after I mark some cells with red color. After these changes I got the printer error.

Anyway, I will check your suggestion, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Gagravarr I tried out to print PDF with Apache PDFBox, but still have this problem - only 5/6 sheets were printed out, then "Error - Sent to printer"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to change the printing protocol from WSD to LPD. After that the file was printed out completely.